# how to send html email which suits for both phone screen and pc screen

Tags: html, email

I use tables to contain my html code. Open it on Browser and use "ctrl+a” + copy + paste to my email compose.
But after receiving that email, I found it is not fixed to the phone's screen size.

I think using code behind (such as C#) might solve this problem but is that possible to just use copy + paste to send a suitable size email to smart phone?

I've tried:

```
<table><tr><td><img style="width:100%;" src="..." alt="..." /></td></tr></table>
```

and

```
<table><tr><td><img style="width:600px;" src="..." alt="..." /></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: @ckpepper02 . For the code, just tried '<table><tr><td><img style="width:100%;" src="..." alt="..." /></td></tr></table>'  and '<table><tr><td><img style="width:600px;" src="..." alt="..." /></td></tr></table>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy and paste method will work for sending email via Outlook, providing your image links are hosted and not relative.

If you want an email that resizes to the viewport, it is quite an artform and a complex subject to cover. For your simple example though, if you'd like an image that resizes to the email viewport, you can use this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" width="100%" alt="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue the last 2 days...

What I know now is: most e-mail clients take @media query statements ->  android won't.

Check this http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @delueg. Is media querie like that: "<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />". It seems table can not use it, is that right?

Comment: Android does accept media queries. Gmail for Android will not.

Comment: @John. Um... sorry i'm still confused. how to use it in tables for html email ?

Comment: @GarlicBread what are you using to send the email? If the html is not showing up, it is because you don't have the right mime type.

Comment: @John. I just use this way: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/how-to-send-an-html-email-from-gmail/ and my code is showing above~ :)

Comment: yes but you can use <style> tag adn use 
@media (min-width:800px){
  .class_xy{
display:none;
}
}
for example

Comment: A fluid email is much simpler and 100% supported. Set your widths to percentages and keep it single column and you'll be right. You can use media queries to style the text larger/smaller, but it gets more complex and less supported if you try to bounce multiple column desktop layouts into single column mobile ones.